# Nginx redirect HTTPS, www, IPv6, HTTP2

Tags: nginx, https, redirect, http2

I'm trying to avoid redirect chains in Nginx, which I am using as a reverse proxy to Apache.

I've been able to find plenty of documentation about redirecting `HTTP` to `HTTPS`.

I've also found plenty of documentation about redirecting `www` to naked domain (or vice versa).

The vhosts/websites are (for the most part) subdomains of my primary website, `example.com`.

**Background:** I am using this configuration because I am most familiar with Apache but I appreciate the performance improvements of Nginx and, more importantly, I have a NodeJS application running on the server and I'd like users to be able to access it without appending a port to the request. Nginx listens on port 80 for HTTP and port 443 for HTTPS and routes requests to the ports that I have configured Apache and NodeJS to use (port 8080 for Apache and port 4000 for Node).

**Edit:** I found the config generator tools at [nginxconfig.io](https://nginxconfig.io) to be very helpful and much of what I got from there has been included unchanged.

For the "main" website, I'm using the `www` subdomain so I need to redirect the following domains to `https://www.example.com`:

```
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://example.com
```

Everything I can find seems to handle this in 2 redirects such as:

`http://example.com` to `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`

The answer in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/634415/nginx-https-www-to-non-www-redirect-issue) (which is actually a redirect of `www` to the naked domain), uses an `if` statement but Nginx docs suggest avoiding `if` statements for performance reasons.

**Question 1**
Is there are way to handle these redirects in one redirect, and without triggering warnings about having blocks with duplicate server names?

**Question 2**
When I set up the block for port 80, what parameters do I need to include if all I am doing is redirecting?

My `.conf` file looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name www.example.com;
    root /var/www/html/example.com;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;

    # security
    include nginxconfig.io/security.conf;

    # logging
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log warn;

    # index.html fallback
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # additional config
    include nginxconfig.io/general.conf;
}

# HTTP redirect
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com;

    include nginxconfig.io/letsencrypt.conf;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

    }
}
```

Do I need to have `include nginxconfig.io/letsencrypt.conf;` in the block for port 80?

Do I need to add `http2` after the `listen` directives in the block for port 80 so that HTTP2 requests over HTTP get redirected to HTTPS while still supporting HTTP2 or is it sufficient to just include the `http2` directive in the block for HTTPS/port 443.

The contents of `nginxconfig.io/letsencrypt.conf` are:

```
# ACME-challenge
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /var/www/_letsencrypt;
}
```

Contents of `.../security.conf` are:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
#add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' http: https: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'" always;
#add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;

# . files
location ~ /\.(?!well-known) {
    deny all;
}
location ~* (?:#.*#|\.(?:bak|conf|dist|fla|in[ci]|log|orig|psd|sh|sql|sw[op])|~)$ {
  deny all;
}
```

I do plan to implement HSTS eventually, but obviously, need to get my basic configuration sorted out first.

Contents of `.../general.conf`:

```
# favicon.ico
location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

# robots.txt
location = /robots.txt {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

# gzip
gzip on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/javascript application/rss+xml application/atom+xml image/svg+xml;
```

Comment: What is in the file `letsencrypt.conf`?

Comment: Potentially relevant: https://serverfault.com/questions/947245/redirect-from-http-example-org-to-https-www-example-org-directly-or-not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way is to have a separate redirect from `http://example.com` to `https://example.com` which then redirects to `https://www.example.com`.

This is because how HSTS headers are used. Further information is at https://www.danielmorell.com/blog/how-to-configure-hsts-on-www-and-other-subdomains

To accommodate this, you need to replace:

```
server_name example.com;
```

with:

```
server_name example.com www.example.com;
```

in your HTTP `server` block.

I assume that `letsencrypt.conf` contains only TLS related settings, and those are not needed in the HTTP `server` block. However, the settings need to be applies to the HTTPS `server` block.

In addition, you need the 301 redirect for your `example.com` domain:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name example.com;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;

    include nginxconfig.io/letsencrypt.conf;

    return 301 https://www.example.com;
}
```